# last insert id in pdo

Tags: mysql, ajax, forms, pdo

I have a form with only one input. When I click the button, an AJAX request is made and the data is sent to the response.php, which uses the pdo library to insert the data to db. Here it is okay, but in the page, there is a success function which loads the data into the form - when the ajax request completes, the result is blank...I need to refresh(F5) the page to see the data ..
Here is this code:

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {
        try{
    $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO DIAGNOSTICO (id_paciente, id_doctor, hconsulta) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    if ($statement->execute(array($_POST['id_paciente'], $_POST['id_doctor'], $_POST['hconsulta'])));
        $dbSuccess = true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $return['databaseException'] = $e->getMessage();
}
 {
echo $conn->lastInsertId(); 
echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id_diagnostico"].'">';
echo '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$row["id_diagnostico"].'">';
echo '<img src="../images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />';
echo '</a></div>'; echo ' Fecha de consulta : ';echo $row["f_diagnostico"]; echo ' <br><br> ';
echo $row["hconsulta"].'</li>';
}
   $dbh = null;  
}
?>
```

It is working, but when in the page, the result returns from the ajax request and shows the id but not the data...I need the data result...can you help me?

best regards!

Comment: What is this AJAX request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using the `lastinsertid` you have to `select` `data` by using

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM DIAGNOSTICO WHERE id_diagnostico= ".$conn->lastInsertId());
$sth->execute();

$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id_diagnostico"].'">';
echo '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$row["id_diagnostico"].'">';
echo '<img src="../images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />';
echo '</a></div>'; echo ' Fecha de consulta : ';echo $row["f_diagnostico"]; echo ' <br><br> ';
echo $row["hconsulta"].'</li>';
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: He is not getting the `result` after `inserting` into `database`, and using `$row` for this he has to fetch record from `db`, he said that he is getting the `last insert id` but bot result. Right?

Comment: yes! I can insert into the db..but not show me in page the result...now with your code @Rohan Kumar I see the print...but I don't know how put it into li...

Comment: @asterix_jv test the above answer I had made changes in it.

Comment: Works!! thank you @Rolan Kumar, great, great support!   best regards

Comment: Ok, @asterix_jv, But its **Rohan Kumar** not `Rolan Kumar`

Comment: Thank you @Rohan Kumar...sorry for changing your name...One last question... if I want to insert order by id_diagnostico give me error...how I need to put order by?  Best Regards!

Comment: Dear @asterix_jv , you can use `order by` for `selecting fields from database` not for `inserting into database`.

Comment: Hi @Rohan Kumar, I know that I need to use order by in select but when I insert in `$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM DIAGNOSTICO WHERE id_diagnostico= ".$conn->lastInsertId() order by id_diagnostico DESC);`    show me this error   `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/----/public_html/----/response.php on line 14`
$sth->execute();`   so I don´t know where put it