# select last id, without insert in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849898/last-insert-id-in-pdo) but i still cant make it work.

Edited:

I want to get the `id's` for **each** of my Fruits without `insert` in PDO.

```
//apple
//orange

foreach($_POST['fruits'] as $fruits) {

     $a = recordFruit($fruits); 

      if(!empty($a)) {
         $id = id_of_this_fruit(); //get ID of apple, then orange. so on..
         echo $id[0]."<br />";
      }
}


function id_of_this_fruit(){
    ...
    $query = "SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
    ...
    $row = $sql->fetchALL();
    return $row;
}
```

Edited: after some changes in the query. my code returns value. but its not returning the recently added data. it shows the old ID prior to the insertion of new fruits.

Comment: Maybe `id` field is not set as `primary key` in database?

Comment: What **recordFruit** function do? and please share your complete code and table structure.

Comment: @developer i have no control of the `recordFruit()` its an API of some sort provided to me by a 3rd party. i just input the variables inside. I just simplified it with my fruit version. I have access to their DB but I dont have the insert privilege.

Comment: Your code does not seem to make a lot of sense, `$a`  does not even seem to be related to `id_of_this_fruit()`. Do you mean to pass that variable to the function? And why would you need the newest ID?

Comment: For the given conditions, you cannot get anything. either this recordFruit can provide you with information or the mission is impossible. The sooner you realize that, the less time you waste for all those wannabe helpers below.

Answer (score 0):

You can get last id by querying with order by and limit if ID is auto increment.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fruits 
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if you are using a table. If you are using the alias with multiple tables in the `WHERE` clause, will fail SQL `Error (1221): Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * FROM fruits  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```